# What is M-aware polyline in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, linear-referencing

Can anybody explain the concept of M-aware geometry?

I want to construct the M-aware polyline by using xy values. Before doing this exercise I want to understand the concept of M-aware and work on it.

Answer (score 5):

An m-aware polyline has the ability to store m-values (in addition to x and y values). M-values are 'measurement' values, for example the distance along a given line. They are often used in linear referencing datasets.

Read more on the concept of linear referencing: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/linear-referencing-datasets-in-arcgis.htm

Answer (score 4):

The M in M-aware stand for Measure and is another coordinate value like an X, Y or Z coordinate on each node.  Measures are typically the relative linear distance of each vertex measured from the start of the line.  M-aware lines are also assigned a unique Route ID and can then be used to create an event table for points or line segments which are defined by including a field for the Route ID value and one or two measure value fields.  This is called Linear Referencing and you can read about it [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm).

Normally you would first use the Point to Line tool to build your xy points into a line first and then you can use that line to create an M-aware line feature class by using the [Create Routes tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/create-routes.htm)

M values are not limited to representing linear distances and could alternatively represent things like the time stamp of each point of a line for animal tracks, for example.