Generating cumulative M-values in QGIS
I have a linear dataset in QGIS each vertex in each line has an X, Y and Z values. I want them to have M values. There is a set M value tool but it only seems to set a single value to each vertex i.e. every vertex in a 200km line has the same m value.
To my mind, the m value should represent the cumulative chainage measure of each vertex from the start to the end. I've searched for a few hours and haven't found anything to change this.

What is m value? How is it calculated?

@BERA https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/385588/172108

I want Fritz definition since there seems to be multiple answers

M can hold any measure (temperature, air pressure, noise level...) not only distances from the starting point. The cumulative distance thing is ofter called linear referencing. There seems to be several plugins for linear referencing available. Install and try what they can do.
